# How to deal Large Dataset using Eloquent?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

In my table there are more than 5.600.000 records. When I try to get records using `PAGINATE(15)`, after a very long processing server response `Internal Server Error` The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, contact@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.". Please help, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm positive the owner of that email will be more than happy to have his email in open plain text for every email sniffer robot to use his address in this winter penis enlargement campaign.

Comment: Have you checked the laravel log to see what it contains? What is your query? When did 5.6M record become a large dataset? It is hard for us to give you any recommendations without at least any error from the log and the query you get an error with. It can be lots of joins without using indexes or it can be totally unrelated to the query, without the error from the log it is not possible to know

Comment: can you show your query? It is not very large dataset, if you have correct index setup it takes no more than ~1sec to query.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) configuration.

You can check your error logs for more info (php error logs or laravel /storage/logs).

It can be [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) or some other setting in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem with `paginate()`. `paginate()` retrieves all the rows in a table and counts the total rows to determine the total no of pages required. Since you have 5600,000 rows in the table, it is taking a long time to retrieve the results which eventually might be reaching `max_execution_time` or `memory_limit`.

I suggest the best way is to use `simplePaginate()`